# Como faço para dar espaços entre a Tag Input

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho um codigo e preciso organizar uma parte dele, porem nao consigo. Preciso inserir um espaço entre alguns input, porem nao sei como faze isso.

```
<tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id=input-atendimento>
                Emergencia<input type="radio" name="atendimento" value="emergencia">
                Urgente<input type="radio" name="atendimento" value="urgente">
                Pouco Urgente<input type="radio" name="atendimento" value="pouco_urgente" checked="checked">
                Não Urgente<input type="radio" name="atendimento"value="nao_urgente">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria de saber como adicionar um espeço entre eles

Comment: Tenta no seu CSS: `#input-atendimento input{ margin-right: 20px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além de dar o espaço que deseja, eu iria um pouco além para melhorar o código. Em vez de restringir o click apenas no `radio`, você pode ampliar para o texto que se refere a ele.

Por exemplo, clicar no texto "Emergência" e marcar o seu `radio`. Apesar de aumentar um pouco o código, melhora e muito a experiência do usuário, principalmente em dispositivos móveis que diminuem o tamanho da tela, e o usuário não precisa clicar exatamente no espacinho do radio, pois clicando no seu texto já o marca.

Para isso inclua cada texto referente ao `radio` em um `label`, e coloque um `id` nos `input`s e um `for` em cada `label` apontando para o respectivo `id`:

```
<label for="_emergencia">Emergencia</label>
<input id="_emergencia" type="radio" name="atendimento" value="emergencia">

<label for="_urgente">Urgente</label>
<input id="_urgente" type="radio" name="atendimento" value="urgente">

<label for="_pouco_urgente">Pouco Urgente</label>
<input id="_pouco_urgente" type="radio" name="atendimento" value="pouco_urgente" checked="checked">

<label for="_nao_urgente">Não Urgente</label>
<input id="_nao_urgente" type="radio" name="atendimento"value="nao_urgente">
```

Coloquei um `_` antes de cada `id` para previnir possíveis conflitos com outras `id`s que possam existir na página.

A questão da margem você pode primeiramente retirar a margem padrão do `radio` e setar uma margem do `radio` para o texto à direita (`20px`), e usar `vertical-align: middle;` no `label` e no `input` para alinhá-los ao meio um com o outro.

```
#input-atendimento label,
#input-atendimento input{
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin: 0;
}

#input-atendimento input{
   margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
#input-atendimento label,
#input-atendimento input{
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin: 0;
}

#input-atendimento input{
   margin-right: 20px;
}

table {
   border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
Clique no texto em vez de clicar diretamente no radio:
<table>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
         <div id=input-atendimento>
            <label for="_emergencia">Emergencia</label>
            <input id="_emergencia" type="radio" name="atendimento" value="emergencia">
            
            <label for="_urgente">Urgente</label>
            <input id="_urgente" type="radio" name="atendimento" value="urgente">
            
            <label for="_pouco_urgente">Pouco Urgente</label>
            <input id="_pouco_urgente" type="radio" name="atendimento" value="pouco_urgente" checked="checked">
            
            <label for="_nao_urgente">Não Urgente</label>
            <input id="_nao_urgente" type="radio" name="atendimento" value="nao_urgente">
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: obrigado me ajudou muito

Comment: De nada amigo! Saiba como agradecer também neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Veja o exemplo com `margin-right` em todos os itens menos para o último pq não há outro elemento a direita.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
}
[type="radio"]:not(:last-of-type) { 
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div id=input-atendimento>
            Emergencia<input type="radio" name="atendimento" value="emergencia">
            Urgente<input type="radio" name="atendimento" value="urgente">
            Pouco Urgente<input type="radio" name="atendimento" value="pouco_urgente" checked="checked">
            Não Urgente<input type="radio" name="atendimento"value="nao_urgente">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```